# Magento: Syncing product/category translations from "Store 1 > German Store View" to "Store 2 > German Store View"

Tags: php, localization, magento

For two different store Views using the same locale, it is easy to manage translations for miscellaneous text that's stored in CSV files. It's just a question of configuring the locale correctly so the correct CSV files will be used.

But my client has entered a bunch of translations for products and categories into the admin by changing the scope to "Store 1 > German" and setting the translations. But now he has Store 2, with a German store view. How does he keep "Store 1 > German Store View" and "Store 2 > German Store View" in sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution - if this is a big issue, you can designate one of the stores as "master" for the translations and create sync script or one time export/import of attributes.

Comment: Do you know of an extension or other solution to accomplish this sync? It seems like it would be a common problem.